# Usefullness of a manual vertex shader optimization?

Tags: shaders, optimization

After having implemented a texturecube RGBA16F to generate shadows for 4 pointlights in one pass (forward shader), I've compared with array[4] of textucube R16F and with texturecuberarray with 4 layers of R16F.

The best performance goes to the array[4] of texturecube which makes sens considering the lower bandwith stress during shadow generation.

To improve again FPS rate, as an exercice, I have tried to take into account AMD's advices on vertex shader optimzation for the best method, especially paking of data and parallelization. My original for loop shader looking like this (I'm using linear attenuation for pointlight);

LColor.w store 1/radius; LPos.w stores 1/(radius^2)

```
    for ( dword l = 0; l< 4;l++)
    {
        txDist = Input.WPos.xyz - LightPos[l].xyz; 
        LL = txShadowArrayCubeMap[l].Sample(samPoint, txDist)+ 0.0001f;
        P = float2(LightPos[l].w, LightColor[l].w)*length(txDist);
        Shadow = (LL < P.x )?0.5f*Shadow:Shadow;
        if ( P.y < 1 ) LColor +=dot(normalize(-txDist), N)*LightColor[l].xyz*(1-P.y);
    }
    LColor *= Shadow;
```

was modified like this (unroll loop and paking of data in float4 because 4 lights)

```
        float3 txProj0 = Input.WPos - LightPos[0].xyz;  
        float3 txProj1 = Input.WPos - LightPos[1].xyz; 
        float3 txProj2 = Input.WPos - LightPos[2].xyz; 
        float3 txProj3 = Input.WPos - LightPos[3].xyz; 
        float4 LN = float4(length(txProj0), length(txProj1), length(txProj2),length(txProj3));
        float4 PL; 
        float4 Shadow4; 
        if ( bShadow ) 
        { 
            float LL0 = txShadowArrayCubeMap[0].Sample(samPoint, txProj0);
            float LL1 = txShadowArrayCubeMap[1].Sample(samPoint, txProj1);
            float LL2 = txShadowArrayCubeMap[2].Sample(samPoint, txProj2);
            float LL3 = txShadowArrayCubeMap[3].Sample(samPoint, txProj3);
            PL = float4(LightPos[0].w, LightPos[1].w, LightPos[2].w, LightPos[3].w)*LN;
            float4 LE = float4(LL0,LL1,LL2,LL3)+float4(0.0001f,0.0001f,0.0001f,0.0001f);    //add bias here 
            Shadow4 = (LE < PL)? float4(0.5f,0.5f,0.5f,0.5f):float4(1,1,1,1);
        }
        PL = mad ( float4(-LightColor[0].w, -LightColor[1].w, -LightColor[2].w, -LightColor[3].w), LN, float4(1,1,1,1));
        LColor += ( PL.x > 0 )? dot(normalize(-txProj0), N)*LightColor[0].xyz*PL.x:0;
        LColor += ( PL.y > 0 )? dot(normalize(-txProj1), N)*LightColor[1].xyz*PL.y:0;
        LColor += ( PL.z > 0 )? dot(normalize(-txProj2), N)*LightColor[2].xyz*PL.z:0;
        LColor += ( PL.w > 0 )? dot(normalize(-txProj3), N)*LightColor[3].xyz*PL.w:0;
        if ( bShadow ) LColor *= Shadow4.x*Shadow4.y*Shadow4.z*Shadow4.w*Shadow;
```

despite the apparent length of this shader it is 5 to 10% faster.

My question is: Is this something valuable in professional game development? Is the rate improvement sufficient to justify the use of this "compact" shader? I see as a drawback the loss of flexibility a for loop gives but this can be compensated by having one shader per fixed number of lights. For instance I have 4 versions of this shader (with float/float2/float3/float4) for 1 to 4 pointlights. Note that just unrolling the loop remains slower than this packing. I'm also interested in suggestions if this shader can be improved.

Comment: This looks like a judgement call you'll need to make, based on the needs of the project. If your GPU budget is very tight, you'll give more priority to that 5-10% savings. If you need to change the shader frequently or adapt to many different situations, you might give more priority to the simpler code and accept a slight increase in cost. That's why they pay you the big bucks: you are a decision maker with your own valuable insights and judgement.

Comment: 5-10% could be the difference between hitting your target framerate or not, it could enable you to run on a wider range of hardware, or it could translate to battery savings on mobile devices - but that all depends on your program and whether these are important tradeoffs to you vs complexity. If it was lower I'd say "don't sweat it", if it was higher I'd say "definitely", but 5-10% is also about the range where it may or may not be worth it.

Comment: Thanks for your advices